# StoryBook canvas:[TypeError: Expected container to be an Element, a Document or a DocumentFragment but got null.] in React-Native

Tags: react-native, testing, storybook

I'm getting a problem in canvas getByText function. All my attempts with different getBy* functions got null. My Code:

```
export const MyButton = ({ onPress, text }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} onPress={onPress} activeOpacity={0.8}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

My play function

```
const MyButtonMeta = {
  title: 'MyButton',
  component: MyButton,

  args: {
    text: 'Hello world',
  },
  decorators: [
    (Story) => (
      <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1 }}>
        <Story />
      </View>
    ),
  ],
};

export default MyButtonMeta;



export const AnotherExample = {
 
  play:async ({ canvasElement }) => {
    const canvas = within(canvasElement);
    const header=  await canvas.getByText('Hello world')
    console.log(header)
    // await userEvent.press(header)
  }
};
```

That is the log of console.log:

```
LOG  [TypeError: Expected container to be an Element, a Document or a DocumentFragment but got null.]
```

Somebody could tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hey react native storybook maintainer here.

This isn't supported on react native since there is no way to select the react nodes at runtime in react native.

The play function should only be used with addon-react-native-web which runs on reactjs storybook